# How to get page by URL in NodeMCU (ESP8266)

Tags: url, get, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to get value in NodeMCU module from my own page, hosted by free hosting. Final URL is: boiler.atwebpages.com/boi.php. First, i perform connect to server:
`client.connect(boiler.atwebpages.com, 80)`

and send request

```
client.println("GET /boi.php HTTP/1.0");
client.println()
```

And here's the problem. First microchip get IP from boiler.atwebpages.com (which is 83.125.22.211) and try to get file boi.php. In fact, it try to access into 83.125.22.211/boi.php, which doesn't exist, so i get 404 error. Is that possible to get information from direct URL or get direct path from IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the Host header with the request:

```
client.println("GET /boi.php HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: boiler.atwebpages.com\r\n");
```